# Comment résoudre ce problème syntax error, unexpected 'Route' (T_STRING), expecting ';'

Tags: php, routes

Route::get('/', [EquipeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Comment: Read this: [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them). P.s. on stackoverflow you must post everything in English

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not in English

Answer (score 0):

one line before this code must has `;` at the end!